# angular - html issue (routing takes place with app component html)

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing

Building a simple application.
The app is loading with the contents of app.component.html.
There are some menu items like About Us page, contact Us page.. etc
The problem is - When I route to any of these pages, the content of app.component.html is displayed along with the content of contact.component.html when I click on contact us page. 
Is there a way to remove the app content when the route to another component has taken place

Comment: Read this article [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app.component.html and create a new component for your home page and do as following in Routes :

```
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {AboutUsComponent} from './aboutus/aboutus.component';
import {ContactUsComponent} from './contactus/contactus.component';



const appRoutes: Routes = [

{path: '', component: HomeComponent},
{path: 'aboutus', component: AboutUsComponent},
{path: 'contactus', component: ContactUsComponent},

]
```

Comment: @Reza - yes I have used the same - the routing is happening all right. The problem is when i route to a new page, both components content are displayed. In your example: On clicking about us page : the content of home page and about us page: both are coming

Comment: @SG17 your app.component.html should only contain a single <router-outlet></router-outlet> and you have to create a new component like i did ( HomeComponent) then cut and paste all of content in app.component.html that you previously had to this new component and  this will just do fine and none of the home component content would show on any of the other pages .